# Can we reuse struct on Swift? Or is there any other way?

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

So I have a user JSON structure that goes like this:

```
- results: {
    meta: {}
    users: []
  },
- status:
```

I want to get the user so the `User` model I implement to get the JSON is like this:

```
struct Response: Decodable {

    let results: Result
    let status: Int
}

struct Result: Decodable {

    let meta: Meta
    let users: [User]
}

struct Meta: Decodable {

    let total_data: Int
    let total_page: Int
}

struct User: Decodable {

    let avatar_url: String
    let created_at: String
    let updated_at: String
    let email: String
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let username: String
}
```

It is working, but when I have another JSON that the structure is similar, let say like this

```
- results: {
        meta: {}
        rooms: []
      },
    - status:
```

And when I create `Room` model, with another `struct Response` on it, it will cause error because it is duplicated declaration.

Is it possible to reuse struct in Swift? Or is there any convenient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: yes you can reuse same `struct` if all your `JSON` requirement met with your  ` structure`.

Comment: Then don't declare it again you can use that same object

Comment: You can reuse yours structs by changing name mapping using `CodingKeys` enum for different json, but I would not suggest doing that. Just implement your model the way your JSON structure suggests object per object.

Comment: Yes you can reuse any type, fell free!!

Comment: You can make typealias

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use generics.

```
struct Response<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let results: Result<T>
    let status: Int
}

struct Result<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let meta: Meta
    let objects: [T]
}

struct Meta: Decodable {    
    let total_data: Int
    let total_page: Int
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let avatar_url: String
    let created_at: String
    let updated_at: String
    let email: String
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let username: String
}

let userResponse: Response<User>?
```

Comment: Generic is best

Comment: @pstued this is awesome

Comment: Suggestion : If you want more generic type then on Result struct replace  with     `let objects: T` and  object should be created with  `let userResponse: Response<Array<Users>>?` will helpful to parse  array  as well as single object  with     `let userResponse1: Response<Users>?`
 in any case

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use generics in the following way:

```
struct Response<ResultType> : Decodable where ResultType : Decodable {
    let results: ResultType
    let status: Int
}
```

and then use that struct via:

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    let something: String
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = "{\"status\":123,\"results\":{\"something\":\"hi\"}}".data(using: .utf8)!
let value = try! decoder.decode(Response<Result>.self, from: data) // will be of type Response<Result>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one option is to reuse `Meta` and `Status`
If you use sm

For user You can replace name

```
struct UserResult: Decodable {

    let meta: Meta
    let users: [User]
}

struct UserResponse: Decodable {

    let results: UserResult
    let status: Int
}
```

and for Room

```
struct RoomResult: Decodable {

    let meta: Meta
    let users: [Room]
}

struct RoomResponse: Decodable {

    let results: RoomResult
    let status: Int
}
```

Comment: It seems to be incorrect. You could achieve it by using *generics*.

Comment: @AhmadF What is the response changed ? and some new field has been added and some field has been removed ? there is no doubt that generic is good

Comment: @AhmadF it is better to keep it separate

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you can use generics to compose the whole struct.

Start with your data models

```
struct User: Decodable {
    let avatar_url: String
    let created_at: String
    let updated_at: String
    let email: String
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let username: String
}

struct Room: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

The goal is to get nice composed types.

```
typealias UserResponse = Response<Result<User, Meta>>
typealias RoomResponse = Response<Result<Room, Meta>>
```

The generics types to build from

```
struct Response<ResultType: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let results: ResultType
    let status: Int
}

struct Result<ItemType: Decodable, MetaType: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let meta: MetaType
    let items: [ItemType]
}
```

Even `Meta` is a separate part of the composition.

```
struct Meta: Decodable {
    let total_data: Int
    let total_page: Int
}
```

Now lets say we need a custom `Meta` for the `Room` response

```
struct PagedMeta: Decodable {
    let current_page: Int
    let page_count: Int
}
```

Here is the new type

```
typealias RoomPagedResponse = Response<Result<Room, PagedMeta>>
```